# Totalling and storing previous data numbers (values) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [Easy Pie Chart](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) and modifying it out a little to include multiple percentages and rotations to make a complete pie chart. This doesn't really involve anything EPC related but thought I would background it.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="home-slider-chart-container">
    <div data-rotate="0" data-percent="2" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
    <div data-rotate="" data-percent="27" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
    <div data-rotate="" data-percent="20" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
    <div data-rotate="" data-percent="40" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
    <div data-rotate="" data-percent="6" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
    <div data-rotate="" data-percent="5" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do, with jQuery, is run through each `.home-slider-chart`  and store the value of the current and all the previous `data-percent` values that came before then I will use it to calculate the rotation number.

So, in my example, the `data-rotate` values in the end would be:

```
<div data-rotate="0" data-percent="2" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
<div data-rotate="29" data-percent="27" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
<div data-rotate="49" data-percent="20" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
<div data-rotate="89" data-percent="40" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
<div data-rotate="95" data-percent="6" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
<div data-rotate="100" data-percent="5" class="home-slider-chart"></div>
```

I thought this would work, but all it is doing is taking the previous percent rather than totalling all the previous ones.

```
$('.home-slider-chart-container .home-slider-chart').each(function() {
    var thisPercentage = $(this).data('percent');
    var prevPercentage = $(this).prevAll().data('percent');
    var percentageTotal = (thisPercentage + prevPercentage);
    var thisRotation = (percentageTotal / 100 * 360);

    $(this).data('rotate', thisRotation);

});
```

I have set up a jsFiddle so you can see what I am trying to do and you can use it as a testing environment https://jsfiddle.net/105o7b5m/1/

Comment: What are you trying to do with `var prevPercentage = $(this).prevAll().data('percent');`?

Comment: Get the data-percent values of what came before. I know this is wrong... so it needs to add together the prev data-percent values.

Comment: prevAll() returns a jQuery object representing all the previous siblings, but the "data" property represents only the FIRST matched element of prevAll()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a variable outside the `.each()` loop that can keep track of the running total and you need to rotate each element only the prior running total (not including the current value) such as:

```
var runningTotal = 0;
$('.home-slider-chart-container .home-slider-chart').each(function() {
    var thisRotation = (runningTotal / 100 * 360);
    $(this).data('rotate', thisRotation);
    // now update the running total for the next segment
    runningTotal += $(this).data('percent');
});
```

Working jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/14rc3zL6/

Comment: You're right. I have used your code suggestion (https://jsfiddle.net/105o7b5m/7/) and the output is 7.2   104.39999999999999   176.4   320.4   342   360 whereas it should start at 0 and ignore the last one (360) any thoughts?

Comment: @braw - I've modified my answer to what I think you want and included a jsFiddle.  You want the start point (e.g. the rotation) of each segment to be the running total of everything that came before NOT counting the current value.

Comment: Thanks for helping this, this works as desired. I think I was nearly there. Really appreciated.